# Abiti da mettere di sopra: giubbino giubbotto e altri

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, translation, etymology

Buongiorno,

Vorrei sapere che differenza c'è tra un cappotto, una giacca, una giacchetta, un giubbino, un giubbotto, e una giubba, e un maglione e un golf.

Perché in inglese che io sappia esiste solo coat, jacket, e top, ma in italiano, quando si tratta di vestiti, sembra che le distinzioni siano più subdole, di e ce ne siano di più. Sarà che è un paese dove la gente presta molta attenzione alla moda, sarà per questo?

Io ho sempre pensato che giacca fosse jacket, ma conosco persone che se dico giacca pensano a qualcosa che in inglese chiamerei semplicemente top.

Grazie per i chiarimenti.

Comment: Oltre a coat, jacket, e top, in un vocabolario inglese trovi tanti altri termini come fleece, fur, hair, pile, wool, parka, blazer, tails, cardigan, pullover, windbreaker, ecc.

Comment: Suggerimento per capire cosa sono: vedi le immagini relative in un motore di ricerca facendo attenzione a modificare ogni volta la lingua impostata per le ricerche.